# How to assign value to variable that fetched from database?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Using "SELECT" query a string fetched from database which included variable name, "Dear $customer_name " in that page $customer_name='John Denie' but in echo it prints "Dear $customer_name" instead of "Dear John Denie"

```
/// in brief codding just to clear idea ///
         $customer_name='John Denie'; 
        "SELECT SMS_text From table"   //SMS_text value in database is Dear $customer_name
        $sms_body=$row["SMS_text"];
echo $sms_body
```

Now this $sms_body echo Dear $customer_name and I want it should print Dear John Denie
as per code $customer_name keep changes here I assigned static value forexample.

I tried {} trim function and other methods but nothing for me. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? How exactly would `trim()` be useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your sms_text == 'Dear $customer_name ...'
you should just add row after

```
$sms_body=$row["SMS_text"];
```

and before

```
 echo $sms_body:
```

you should add this row:

```
$sms_body= str_replace('$customer_name',$customer_name,$sms_body);
```

Perhaps your expectations are based on the idea that,

**echo $sms_body;** is equivalent to **echo "Dear $customer_name ...";**, in fact, you have **echo $sms_body;** is equivalent to **echo 'Dear $customer_name ...';**

Comment: no unfortunately, did not work even I tried replacing with different variable.
$customer_names="ABC ZYZ";
 $sms_body= str_replace("$customer_name",$customer_names,$sms_body);

Comment: Put the variable in a single quoted literal or PHP will try and expand it , so do `$sms_body= str_replace('$customer_name',$customer_name,$sms_body);`

Comment: yes, sorry my bad it should be single quotes